# Синхронизация потоков примитивами

Tags: c#, .net

Рихтер в своей книге пишут, что использование примитивов режима ядра снижает производительность из-за доступа из управляемого кода в неуправляемый.

А как дела обстоят с этим в неуправляемых языках производительности?

Так же Рихтер приводит в пример гибридные механизмы блокировки, когда только в крайнем случае вызывается синхронизация режима ядра и реализованные им самим.

Почему Майкрософт не сделали так же из коробки?

Да, движения в этом направлении есть, всякие slim-конструкции, но они вроде не покрывают все примитивы.

Comment: В неуправляемой коде дела обстоят точно так же: системные вызовы везде дороги. Почему гибридные решения не используются везде? Потому что идеального решения не существует, и у каждого решения своя ниша.

Comment: Простите, что не сделали из коробки? Если это не объект ядра, то его должна поставлять рантайм-библиотека языков программирования, а не ОС.

Comment: Но вообще-то, они таки написали внутрипроцессные примитивы. Например: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937(v=vs.85).aspx и вообще https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681924(v=vs.85).aspx